# Why is my question being voted closed as duplicate, when I have made it clear that it's not?

Tags: discussion, support

For some reason, my question keeps getting close votes, claiming it is a duplicate of another question:

[How can I configure iPhone to stop prompting me to setup Apple Pay?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/310314/how-can-i-configure-iphone-to-stop-prompting-me-to-setup-apple-pay)

From my perspective, I made it absolutely, unequivocally, crystal clear that these two questions are not the same, and the solution is not the same. Yet folks are still piling on the close votes.

What more can I do to keep my question from closing?

Comment: I've cleared the pending close votes now, so the post shouldn't show up in the review queue any longer.

Comment: @patrix I did this by voting to leave open in the queue, it was already removed :)

Comment: @grgarside It still showed a (3) when looking at the post directly, so in my understanding it was still in the review queue as it hadn't gathered the five votes in either direction. AFAIK mod votes in the review queue are non-binding.

Comment: @grgarside But that's an interesting question in itself. The question timeline says that the vote completed 9 hours ago (that probably was your vote then), but the two close votes got only cleared when I force-closed the question a few minutes ago. Hmm.

Comment: @patrix Good point about the 3 votes showing on the post itself, but the mod vote on the review queue is binding either way and the queue item shows ["review completed"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/review/close/224461). The timeline constantly confuses me because of how items are ordered by creation, then their removal/"cleared" status is ‘inserted’ in

Comment: The question was not closed and received a great answer. Thanks for your help, all.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there's anything you need to do at this point. Your question is still open and two votes away from being closed, and your edit is helpful in pointing out how the potential duplicate does not answer the problem.

I don't think it's necessary nor productive to edit your question for each close vote you receive unless another comment is raised with separate concerns.

Just because your question receives close votes, that doesn't mean it's unanimous. It goes without saying that many people visited your question and didn't vote to close it, and also someone in the close vote review queue [voted ‘leave open’](https://apple.stackexchange.com/review/close/224461) (and I have also done the same).

Your first edit clarifying how it's not a duplicate was good. I'd say leave it and focus on looking for an answer to the question rather than meta concerns. You are always welcome to bring the discussion to [Ask Different Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38/ask-different-chat), whether before or after a question is closed, for further opinions and feedback on your question.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and your answers.